# Rpres code stacked

Tags: css, rpres

My Rpres table output is stacked, is there an easy way around this? For example, I have 9 columns but it prints them as 3,2,4. There are really more than enough space for all columns to be printed.

I tried converting the data to different table type, but didn't work (data.table as well as a tibble).

Answer (score 0):

I just found it:

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(width = 400)
```
````

This should do the trick (adjust 400 as needed)